# Reading pairs of integers until newline in text input file

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, ifstream, polynomials

Hey guys so I have a question. I want to read pairs of integers (with the first being the coefficient, and the second being the exponent) and each of these pairs is a node in a linked list. I'll keep populating the linked list with these pairs until it sees a newline or enter key in the input text file.

The next line it'll start again, so the input file will look like

```
-1 0 6 2 3 2 5 6 1 6

2 5 3 2 4 2 5 7 2 7
```

where after reading it'll be two different polynomials, i.e.

- Polynomial 1 =  `-1 + 6x^2 + 3x^2 + 5x^6 + x^6`
- Polynomial 2 = `2x^5 + 3x^2 + 4x^2 + 5x^7 + 2x^7`

or 2 different linked lists one for each polynomial. Because currently the way I have it if I just use like

```
while (infile >> coefficient >> exponent)
{
     polynomialA.listInsert(coefficient, exponent);
}
```

It'll read both lines and make a really long single polynomial.

edit: Sorry, I guess I was unclear. Question was - how to make ifstream keep reading pairs of intgers until it reaches a newline character in a text file.

Comment: Good. What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear. I just wanted to know how to make ifstream keep reading pairs of intgers until it reaches a newline character in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can break it into lines, then tokens: Tip: Use `std::stringstream` along with `std::getline`

```
std::string line;
std::getline(infile, line)  //Read the whole line
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(ss >> coefficient >> exponent)  //read the pairs
        polynomialA.listInsert(coefficient, exponent);
}

std::getline(infile, line)  //read another whole line
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(ss >> coefficient >> exponent)  //read the pairs
        polynomialB.listInsert(coefficient, exponent);
}
```

Of course, the above can be written in a better way, but, I will leave that to you.